# Console SpringBoot exibindo caracteres inválidos

Tags: spring-boot

Bom dia, recentemente comecei usar o SpringBoot como framework, nos primeiros dias meu console estava sendo exibido normalmente, mas ele parou de exibir corretamente e começou a mostrar caracteres inválidos e também parou de exibir as cores nos logs de **INFO**, **WARNING** e **ERROR**. Ficando apenas como a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se é possível corrigir esse problema na ferramenta.

Answer (score 0):

algum tempo depois de postar essa pergunta eu encontrei um vídeo com a solução para o problema, e decidi compartilhar aqui, para caso mais alguém passe por esse problema, pode encontrar a solução mais rápido. O vídeo está disponível nesse [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLrK9PctVAk) para consulta.

Para corrigir o problema, basta acessar o seguinte caminho no SprinBoot:

`Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace`

Dentro da janela que irá ser exibida, procurar por `ANSI Console`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de localizar basta instalar essa extensão, caso ela já estiver instalada, verifique se ela possui atualizações pendentes (Era oque estava acontecendo no meu caso).

Após verificar a extensão, basta reiniciar o framework, caso ainda não funcione, adicione o código `spring.output.ansi.enabled=always` no application.properties da aplicação.

Espero que isso ajude.